# Windows 10 - clean install is activated

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

**TL;DR:** Clean Windows 10 install shows as activated and I have no idea why!

**Full context:**

I recently build a new PC and am intending on selling my old one as a full system.  My intent was to do a clean Windows install and to leave it unauthenticated, letting the buyer decide how they want to activate it.

I've pulled all the drives from the old machine, installed a brand new NVMe drive, and done a clean Windows 10 install from a USB created on the new (Win 11) machine.

During install, you have to create/use a Microsoft account so I created a new email address to use to make sure it wasn't associated with my personal account.

I'm a bit surprised then that when I check the activation status in Windows, it says it's activated with a key tied to my Microsoft account.

**Should I care?**

My main concern is that it's been activated with the same key as my new machine and this will cause problems for one or other PC in the future.  Is there any way to check what key (even partial) has been used to activate Windows?

I'm also curious how this happened - only things I can think of:

1. When creating the install media on my new build, it copies the key
   (seems unlikely, didn't happen when creating the install media for
   the new build on the old machine - I had to activate with a
   typed in key)
2. I left the old OS hard drive connected and it activate from the
   key used in that install (also seems unlikely since I haven't
   booted into that install since doing the new one)
3. The throwaway email address for the install account had a key
   associated with it (also unlikely since it includes a partial
   postcode!)
4. Microsoft no-longer care about Win 10 and just activate all new
   installs (seems highly unlikely!)

Comment: You'll need to login to your Microsoft account online and remove that system from your devices list, as activations are tied to the motherboard's hardware ID and the email, or aliases, attached to the Microsoft account; once done, run Windows Update and it should de-activate. Win10+ activates via Windows Update.  **(1)** Activation keys can't be copied to a Windows install ISO without being intentional about it since it has to be added to an `unattend.xml` answer file; **(2)** Not how activation occurs; **(3)** If that email was an alias, that would activate; **(4)** Microsoft still cares lol

Comment: Was the machine upgraded from an older version during the period windows 10 had free upgrades?

Comment: also check the "Activation" under settings - and let us know what it says

Comment: Machine in question was originally installed from USB (as in, a purchased version of Windows 10, non OEM, that came boxed with a USB stick and activation key).  Never been reinstalled.

Have logged into my personal Windows account.  Both old and new machines were showing (with the old PC named as per the original OS install) so have removed the old machine from there.

The new install is still showing as activated after a reboot.  Logging in with the throwaway email to windows, I only see the old machine with the new name I gave it with the clean install.

Comment: In windows, the activation screen says "Windows is activated with a digital licence linked to your Microsoft account"

Comment: @Ben - If the license is a Retail license, there is a solution to this problem, use the command to change the product key to the appropriate generic key for the edition you are running [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kms-client-activation-keys#windows-11-and-windows-10-semi-annual-channel-versions).  You will want to uninstall the current [key](https://www.howtogeek.com/124286/how-to-uninstall-your-windows-product-key-before-you-sell-your-pc/#uninstalling-your-product-key) before you change it to one of the generic keys using `slmgr /ipk`

Comment: I have in the past transferred a Windows installation to a new machine by creating an image of the machine, unregistered the original key, and activated a new key while keeping the original machine activated. However, both machines are always in use, and I have never reinstall Windows on either machine.  Both machines are connect to my Microsoft Account, you would still want to remove the device from your MSA, to sell your device.

Comment: "Is there any way to check what key" - [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases) is the only tool I know that will show you the correct Windows key.

Comment: @Ramhound This looks promising.  If I understand right:
I can use /upk [activation_id] command to remove the current activation.
I don't understand the page about using/ipk to add a generic key though.  I'd like to leave the system with windows installed but not activated.  If I just use /upk, is that where I get to?

Answer (score 1):

First, when installing Windows 10, a Microsoft account is not mandatory.
The button to press is artfully done in small letters at the bottom
of the screen, but you can force Windows to create a local account.
I would recommend this over selling a computer that is registered
to any account of yours (no matter how dummy).

Second, If Windows 10 was ever activated on this computer, then
it is now remembered by the Microsoft activation servers using
its hardware fingerprint, also called digital entitlement.
Although you have replaced some hardware elements, the computer
can be recognized by the major elements that remains, such as
the motherboard, and will be activated automatically.

If the computer was bought with a Windows license
pre-installed (OEM),
then its serial is probably stored with the firmware and
used for activation automatically for any installation.
(This is an alternative explanation for Windows being activated.)

Comment: Digital entitlement IIRC is for those systems upgraded from windows 7 up

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike: See [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/digital-entitlement-activation-methods-windows-10).

Comment: Does it still have that option?  I swear I checked everywhere for a way to make a local account only!

No hardware changes except the SSD so could well just be activated from hardware fingerprint.

Has always been a Win 10 machine, originally installed from boxed USB of Win 10 (non OEM)

Comment: @harrymc, thank you for that explanation. It is disquieting to know that once a Microsoft account is used with a machine, MS associates that machine with the account practically forever.

Comment: To avoid re-installation, see [Switch your Windows 10 device to a local account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/switch-your-windows-10-device-to-a-local-account-eb7e78a9-88ee-9bc3-8f06-831b56e339fd). For the initial installation, this is called "Offline account", see [How to set up Windows 10 with local account](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-windows-10-local-account)

Comment: OK, have:
-Created a local admin account
-Deleted the windows account user
-Only user is now local admin
-Run windows update
-Restart

Still showing activated!

Comment: The computer will stay activated forever, as long as its license and hardware fingerprint are stored in the Microsoft activation servers. You will need to call Microsoft Support to have it deleted, but it can't be deleted if the license belongs and was sold with the computer.

Comment: A Windows license is NOT stored in the BIOS of a system.   Where are people getting that ridiculous concept from? It's stored in the ACPI table, it's certainly accessible from UEFI, and closely related but it's never been stored in the BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: @Ramhound: OK, changed this to the vague "stored with the firmware".

Answer (score 0):

If you are selling it,  make a Windows ISO (so no account), format the main drive, and supply a bootable Windows ISO to the buyer.

They can install and activate as they wish.

One extra step (install which is quick).

Then the new install will not and cannot be tied to you.

I have had removed devices reactivate, so that is why I promote the above. Activation is Windows combined with the specific machine.

Comment: The author could use Rufus, select the option to be allowed to create an account it linked to a MSA, since both the current version of Windows 10 & Windows 11 requires it by default.  All the option does, is perform a small tweak automatically, that can be done by yourself manually. They could also make sure, their license isn’t detected, by using the generic key during the installation process.